# How can I setup multiple web service instances on the same server?

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, rest, server

I have a remote server providing REST services to a mobile app. Everything is working good. I'm new to PHP, so I might be on the wrong track, though.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

and this is the beginning of my PHP script:

```
<?php

    require_once("Rest.inc.php");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    class API extends REST {

        // setup constants

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();              // Init parent contructor
            $this->dbConnect();                 // Initiate Database connection
        }

        private function dbConnect(){
            $this->db = mysql_connect(self::DB_SERVER,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);

            if($this->db)
                mysql_select_db(self::DB,$this->db);
        }

        public function processApi(){

            $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['rquest'])));

            if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0) {
                $this->$func();
            } else {
                $this->response('',404);                // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
            }

        }

        private func ...

        etc.
```

I would like to duplicate this environment on the same server. However, I'm not having much luck with this. I copied the relevant files/folders to a new sub-folder at the domain, inserted the `.htaccess` file, and re-booted the server, but the proper routing does not take place there. I just get "not found on server" errors. I have checked all the file permissions. Was this the right approach to create another instance of the server?

Comment: You might want the `<VirtualHost>` section in your Apache configuration. In most Apache2 installations on linux the vhost configuration can be found in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Copy and modify the default, then enable site with `a2ensite sitename`. Sitename ist the filename without `.conf`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, @Quasimodosclone!

Comment: You don't need to reboot after every configuration change, just restart the Apache service `apache2ctl restart` or `service apache2 restart` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`